# create index based on categorical variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a series of dataframe, within which, I have variable that identifies the "start", and "mid" observations.  There is always one start observation, and one or more mid observations, if each group I'd like to create.  These categories were assigned based on other variables in my dataframe.

I would like a way (preferably in dplyr), for R to create a new group for each set of first and middle observations, so that every time a "start" appears in my initial variable, a new category is created in the second.

E.G.

```
     Var1     Var2
 [1] "start"  "A"
 [2] "mid"    "A"
 [3] "start"  "B" 
 [4] "mid"    "B"
 [5] "mid"    "B"
 [6] "mid"    "B"
 [7] "mid"    "B"
 [8] "start"  "C"
 [9] "mid"    "C"
[10] "mid"    "C"
```

Comment: So you have `Var1` and want to create `Var2`?

Comment: @Gregor yes, Var1 exists, and I'd like to create Var2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use, e.g.,

```
(df$Var2 <- cumsum(df$Var1 == "start"))
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3
```

if you want just integer to represent the groups or, as in your example,

```
(df$Var2 <- LETTERS[cumsum(df$Var1 == "start")])
# [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

In `dplyr` that corresponds to

```
df %>% mutate(Var2 = cumsum(Var1 == "start"))
df %>% mutate(Var2 = LETTERS[cumsum(Var1 == "start")])
```